# Can I setup two different VPN connections on a single Windows Server 2003 box?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I'd like to setup my Windows Server 2003 VPN system as follows:

User A connects to public IP 1.2.3.4
/
Firewall redirects 1.2.3.4 to internal IP 10.10.1.1 which is an IP setup on the Windows Server 2003 box running VPN
/
The 10.10.1.1 VPN server assigns an IP of 10.10.2.2

---

User B connect to public IP 4.3.2.1
/
Firewall redirects 4.3.2.1 to internal IP 10.10.1.2 which is a 2nd IP setup on the same Server 2003 box running VPN
/
The 10.10.1.2 VPN server assigns an IP of 10.10.3.3

Is this possible or do I need two seperate VPN servers to setup such a configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a lot of experience in this area, but a while back a co-worker approached another more experienced one who wanted to do this from home so his various *nix assets could look into our network from behind a crappy VPN client with nothing but Windows 32-bit support (sounds like Crappoint).  A little off-topic, but he said this type of thing is exactly what [Routing and Remote Access](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787456(WS.10).aspx) is for on a Windows box.  Do you know how to configure that?